# Trying to run PyCUDA I get a LogicError message

Tags: python, cuda, nvidia, pycuda

I'm trying to getting started with PyCUDA and parallel computing.
I'm working on a 2012 iMac (High Sierra 10.13 NVIDIA GeForce GTX). 
This is a part of a simple tutorial I was trying:

```
import pycuda
import pycuda.driver as drv

drv.init()
print("%d device(s) found." % drv.Device.count())
```

But I get this error without any other detail:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


 File "<ipython-input-8-87f980c8ed7f>", line 4, in <module>
    drv.init()

LogicError
```

Also, the CUDA panel in preferences shows the annoying "update required" message even if both CUDA and GPU drivers are up to date...Don't know if the two problems are connected.

Comment: Did you verify your CUDA install? Instructions are in the CUDA Mac install guide

Comment: I did, I'll do it another time to check that I didn't skip any passage. Thanks for the suggestion ;)

Comment: *I meant "one more time"...
I just found out there was a problem with Apple clang (my version was too recent), had that fixed but I'm still unable to use PyCUDA.